# Unable to install new software/check for updates eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, networking, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to install subclipse on my desktop so i can use subversion.

When I was at school with my laptop, the installation worked well and i was able to update and commit on the subversion, but, while i was at home, i tried to update and nothing worked. Then I tried on my desktop to install the subclipse plugin without success.

When I go to "Help>install new software>Work With Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"

Nothing appears on the software view except "pending..."

The thing I don't understand is that i'm not using a proxy at home, so i don't understand why it's freezing at this step.

Then, I tried to change my eclipse version but it didn't worked
I also tried to change my network settings without success

Anyone had the same problem before or know how to fix it ?

EDIT 1 : While waiting for the pending thing to resolv i had an error :
"Unable to read repository at http: //download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http: //download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml.
Connection has been shut down"

Comment: Well, this page doesn't exist: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml I get a 404 error if I try to open this in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue today with a new eclipse Kepler installation on a machine with Java 7. We eventually got it to work by having eclipse run on a Java 6 JRE instead.

To do this, add

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
```

Above the -vmargs line in your eclipse.ini file (which should be next to your eclipse.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have extra whitespace between `:` and `/`

Comment: It was because I couldn't insert 2 links in my question (I'm not experienced enough on stack overflow ^^')