# Error eclipse kepler when trying to install new software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I installed Eclipse kepler recently and I am having trouble installing new softwear. When I try to reload the repository site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler I get an error every time:

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201309270900/content.jar.
Read timed out
```

I have tried every solution mentioned on this site, but nothing works for me.

Help me please, I really need this to work!!

Comment: Do you really have a space between 'http' and '://...."? Because you shouldn't!

Comment: No, that's because I cannot use links in my message ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not behind a proxy or firewall it might be an issue with Java 7. Running your eclipse on Java 6 might fix it, more details here:

[Unable to install new software/check for updates eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584987/unable-to-install-new-software-check-for-updates-eclipse/21211066#21211066)

Comment: Btw, I fixed it by simply editing the update site URL and adding the port number. So the new URL reads `http://download.eclipse.org:80/releases/kepler`

Answer (score 0):

The message means that there is a firewall between Eclipse and it's update server. Make sure you have configured the proxy settings correctly in Eclipse.

Note: Eclipse usually uses "Native" as default proxy setting. I have seen at least one instance where Eclipse wasn't able to read the proxy settings from Windows. If it fails for you, ask your system admins for the correct values for you and configure Eclipse manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm very new to all this, so I don't know what my proxy settings are and what they should be. I have however tried turning my firewall of and tried both native and direct  and nothing worked.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I'm not behind a firewall or a proxy. I fixed it by simply editing the update site URL and adding the port number. So the new URL reads `http://download.eclipse.org:80/releases/kepler`

Comment: @jrharshath: If you use Windows, then there is a built-in firewall. I don't see how adding the port will help since `80` is the default port for HTTP and the time out means that somewhere, a firewall does eat the packages.

Comment: I don't see how either - it just does. Perhaps some bad bug in how Eclipse parses the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of adding the port number as suggested above, i.e., http://download.eclipse.org:80/releases/luna worked for me.  In my case, I was using Luna.